# javafx Color parsing

Tags: java, parsing, javafx, colors

Trying to let users select a custom Color scheme for their display.

User Input is turned into a javafx.scene.paint.Color c1.
c1 is a valid Color. However, when i feed it into the setStyle method there is a parser error:

```
    System.out.println("c1 values: R" + c1.getRed()+ " G:"+ c1.getGreen()+" B:" + c1.getBlue());
    Button test = new Button("test");
    test.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + c1);
    Scene login = new Scene(test,640,480);
    stage.setScene(login);
    stage.show();
```

c1 is a valid Color: 
**"c1 values: R0.30588236451148987 Gb0.6745098233222961 B:1.0"**

However there is a parsing error:
**"WARNING: CSS Error parsing '*{-fx-background-color: 0x4eacffff}: Unexpected token '0x' at [1,24]"**

I suspect the Color (which returns doubles) is clashing with -fx-background-color which is expecting a HEX ( ? )
Am i using the tools wrong or do i need to unpack the doubles manually and recast to HEX?

Answer (score 6):

Don't rely on `Color.toString()` to generate a valid string that can be parsed by the CSS parser. The [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#toString--) are pretty explicit about this:

> Returns a string representation of this `Color`. This method is **intended to be used only for informational purposes**. The content and format of the returned string might vary between implementations. The returned string might be empty but cannot be null.

(my emphasis).

You can format a color in a web-friendly hex format with

```
String webFormat = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x",
    (int) (255 * c1.getRed()),
    (int) (255 * c1.getGreen()),
    (int) (255 * c1.getBlue()));
```

If you want to allow transparency, you could do something like

```
String webFormat = String.format("rgba(%d, %d, %d, %f)",
    (int) (255 * c1.getRed()),
    (int) (255 * c1.getGreen()),
    (int) (255 * c1.getBlue()),
    c.getOpacity());
```

Then of course use

```
test.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + webFormat + ";");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very helpful.